# Find y in table of values $y=-(x+5)(2x+3)(x-2)(x-4)$

Tags: polynomials

Im struggling now. How to find this y in table values
Im working for few hours for this

in x - intercept = $-5,3/2,2,4$
And in y - intercept = $60$

in table values $x$ is $-6,-4,-0.5,3,5$
and in y = ?

I tried substituting the $x$ but i dont get it

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I don't understand the post at all.  You have a polynomial in the title.  To make a table of values you just plug in the $x$ values you want and compute $y$.  What are we supposed to do with the intercepts?

Comment: Isn’t this very similar to your previous question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336567/find-table-values-of-this-y-x-4x-2x1x4

Comment: Did you mean $x$-intercepts $-5, \color{red}-3/2,2,4?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plug in:

$x=-6$  means $-(-1)(-9)(-8)(-10)=-720$ same for the rest of them.

$x=5$ means    $-(5+5)(2(5)+3)(5-2)(5-4)=-390$

Please know that you can use free software such as Demos Graphing Calculator  to graph your functions and read off the values from your graph.